# How to setup R with LyX?

Tags: r, lyx

I wish to setup R with LyX.  Going through the web I found many resources.

The "official" text doesn't seem to be the most up to date:  http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxWithRThroughSweave

I followed most of the steps here:  http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LaTeX/SweaveR/lyx_with_r_and_sweave_instructions.pdf
But was it really needed?  Or is LyX 2.x makes some of them obsolete?
From reading this post: http://yihui.name/en/2011/05/sweave-and-pgfsweave-in-lyx-2-0-x-experimental/
I was not so sure anymore.

So my question is - what is the most up to date explanation on how to set up and use LyX with R?

Also - what editor do you find it useful to work with in combination with LyX?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought LyX had its own WYSIWYG(ish) front end, therefore it wouldn't make sense to edit LyX files in another editor ... ?

Comment: Both Ramnath and Ben are right.  In LyX 2.0, Sweave support is out-of-the-box. Open a new document, go Document -> Settings -> Modules, then Add Sweave. Be sure to highlight your chunks and set to the "Chunk" environment, and you should be all set.  Don't even need Ctrl+Enter any more.

Comment: Ben - so does LyX include syntax highlighting of R and the likes?  Do you develope your code in LyX or in something else which you combine with LyX ?

Comment: G. Jay - thank you for the reply.  Might I ask you if you know of any updated documents which explains how to use these features?

Comment: @Tal. Unfortunately, `LyX` does not do syntax highlighting for `R` code. If you use `pgfSweave`, you can get syntax highlighting in the compiled `pdf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `LyX 2.0` with `Sweave` and `pgfSweave` on a daily basis. `LyX 2.0` comes loaded with a module called `Sweave` which immediately allows you to use `Sweave` in your documents. If you plan to use `pgfSweave`, you need to (a) download the `pgfSweave` module and (b) install some converters. Details are available in the third link you indicated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Ramnath - thank you very much.  Could you point me to some of the more updated documents that show how to use these features?

Comment: I've been working on this for a long while, and I believe pgfSweave will finally get into LyX officially (an optimistic estimation is LyX 2.0.2). However, you do not have to wait for an official release of LyX -- Gregor's original article in R News has explained basically all the mechanics, although LyX 2.0 can save lots of troubles he had at that time. I do not quite recommend other resources, since it has been a really big problem that too many guides (including mine) are around; some are not completely correct and some are outdated.